# Why aren't my sub pages loading when they are in location blocks in the nginx configuration?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have a certain subdomain: /var/www/test.domain.com. Now I would like to have multiple pages, so an /about page and a /contact page for example. The homepage works just fine. For some reason I cannot get these subpages to load.

Currently I have 3 files in my /var/www/test.domain.com folder

- index.html
- about.html
- contact.html

I was under the impression that I did not have to create different location blocks for all my subpages, but I am not sure about this. My 'default' location block looked like this:

```
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
```

However, since that did not work, I also tried this:

```
server {
  root /var/www/test.domain.com;

  server_name test.domain.com;

  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location /about {
    root /var/www/test.domain.com;
    index about.html;
  }

  location /contact {
    root /var/www/test.domain.com;
    index contact.html;
  }
}
```

I restart nginx but the /about page and /contact page returns a 404. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to access `about.html` using the URL `/about` and not the URL `/about.html`? Does the latter URL work?

Comment: @RichardSmith Ahh, yes. /about.html does work. Never thought of that. How can I make it so that /about will render the about.html page? I don't really like the extension in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the `about.html` file with the URL `/about` - you could use a `$uri.html` term in the [`try_files` statement](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
}
```